# SHA1 bit-oriented test vector gives wrong digest under openssl

Tags: hash, openssl, cryptography, sha1

So I came accross this list of test vectors to test the validity of a SHA1 implementation (which you can find at the bottom of http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/secure-hashing.html)

The majority of the test vectors called "short" (because their size is less than the block size), pass. However, for all the long test vectors, openssl outputs a digest that is different from the one expected.

Example :

```
Msg = d372b4bf97daa3be77e0d78c123c7bb39dde10c82824c83f2250308320391247da419a167686b7320a5dc49b5cfc686eec76bb7034edaaeb2e029cb91791569e739c1bdb518418ffd07f0001e0

Expected MD = c60a02fffa45deccb075e386be3aa9313c2df4f2

Openssl output = 77 2d ff f3 54 31 2c df 93 e1 94 2f 10 91 f7 f8 78 61 91 c1
```

N.B : The test vectors are made for bit-oriented implementation. What I understand is that this kind of implementation can calculate the digest of messages that have a size which is not necessarily a byte multiple.

Anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question, you're trying to verify the bit mode, but OpenSSL only supports byte mode.  Or, at least, they've only ever been issued a FIPS CAVP certificate for byte mode: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/shs/shaval.html#2465

```
SHA-1    (BYTE-only)
SHA-224  (BYTE-only)
SHA-256  (BYTE-only)
SHA-384  (BYTE-only)
SHA-512  (BYTE-only)
```

If you need a library which has been certified as providing correct answers for BIT values, search that list for "SHA-1 (BIT)".  There are a couple, no idea how many of them are consumable API, though.

Or, byte align your data.

Answer (score 1):

So in response to your comments, I believe the crucial difference in output when you are using the NIST test vectors is that the specified length is very important when doing bit-oriented output. With byte-oriented output, if the NIST message was `98`, you can feel confident that the correct input to your SHA algorithm is the bytes `b10011000`. However if it were bit oriented, it could have `len = 6` for example, in which case the correct input to your algorithm is `b100110`. Or `len = 7` with `b1001100`.